# How to display number with it decimal part in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on angularjs i have getting this problem

`{{420/60}} will display 7`

that is fine for me.

But when i am try this with 450 then it will display 7.5 i want to display only 7 i.e only integer number.

```
{{450/60 }} will display 7.5 but need only 7
```

if i used this

`{{450/60 | number : 0}}  then output is 8`

because it will round of the text.please help me i want to display only 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `$scope.Math = window.Math` in your controller:

```
  var app = angular.module('app',[]);
  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.Math = window.Math;
  });
```

Then in your HTML, you can use Math.floor:

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
     {{ Math.floor(12/5) }} // outputs 2
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a directive like so:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('floor', function(){
    return function(n){
        return Math.floor(n);
    };
});
```

Then you can simply do `{{ 450/60 | floor }}`.

Comment: Thanks but need to set scope also as $scope.Math = window.Math;

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry about the omission, I actually edited the answer and went in a different direction.